# Get only on UUID instead of all

Tags: regex

I have the following log message:

```
"Record was found. Existing Id : 16786131-5d05-4545-92c6-3a24b92843bd Incoming Id : 16786131-5d05-4545-92c6-3a24b92843bd"
```

I'm using following regex to extract uuids from message:

```
\b[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}\b
```

What If I only want to extract uuid with prefix `Existing Id :`

How can I do that?

https://rubular.com/r/icNcb88Z5mO2TN

Answer (score 1):

something like `\bExisting Id : ([a-f0-9-]+)\b`

that is:

word boundary , literal string "Existing Id : " followed by >0 repetitions from the set (hex letters and digits and -) and then a boundary.

Comment: But this also matches `Existing Id :`. I only want match uuid.

Comment: nope, the () brackets are a capturing group.